# MySpace integration with Android

Tags: android, myspace

Hi I'm trying to integrate MySpace with my Android app. As I'm new to this, can you please tell me where to start? Are there any instructions I need to follow to achieve this?

Provide me some links or blogs that will help to do that.

Comment: myspace is a social networking site like a facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see these tutorials for  integrating MySpace with your Android app:

http://code.google.com/p/myspace-android-sdk/wiki/HowToUse

[MySpaceID SDK for Java Android](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category%3aMySpaceID_SDK_for_Java_Android)

http://developer.myspace.com/

You can download MySpace Android SDK from [Here](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category%3aMySpaceID_SDK_for_Java_Android) for integrating MySpace in your application

Answer (score 1):

Use SocialAuth Library to integrate Myspace

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/